# querying for duplicates in 2 tables SQL server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table `table1` containing only the duplicate `person_number` and its corresponding `account_number`.  How do I query for these duplicate `person_number` from main table `master_table` which has no `person_number` column but only the `account_number` column?

```
table1
```

| person_number | account_number |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 4 |
| 15 | 5 |

```
master_table
```

| account_number | account_balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 238989 |
| 2 | 4889895 |
| 3 | 68897 |
| 4 | 298729 |
| 5 | 387745 |
| 6 | 354655 |
| 7 | 553455 |
| 8 | 35545 |

I would like to filter the `master_table` to only contain the `account_number` present in  `table1`

```
resultant_table_of_duplicates
```

| account_number | account_balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 238989 |
| 2 | 4889895 |
| 3 | 68897 |
| 4 | 298729 |
| 5 | 387745 |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: **Consumable** sample data and expected results will help us help you here. Your attempts will also be of benefit.

Comment: your question is not clear,Why is the account number in both tables different?can you send expected results?you want join two table with account number?

Comment: @abolfazlsadeghi , I corrected earlier mistakes. DO let me know if the problem is clear now. Sorry, newbie to stackoverflow

Comment: @ThomA, do let know if this is enough context\

Comment: Seem like an `EXISTS` is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed in the comments section, one idea to carry out this task is using the [`EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) operator inside the `WHERE` clause, by checking all records from mastertable whose "*account_number*" can be found inside table1.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mastertable m
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM table1 t 
             WHERE m.account_number = t.account_number)
```

**Output**:

| account_number | account_balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 238989 |
| 2 | 4889895 |
| 3 | 68897 |
| 4 | 298729 |
| 5 | 387745 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Uln6eEV1).

Comment: in the sub query, what value does  "1" hold?

Comment: It holds truth. You could have used any numerical/string value and would have been just fine. Any non-false value is able to satisfy the `EXISTS` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.account_number,sum(account_balance) from master_table a
inner join table1 b on a.account_number=b.account_number
group by a.account_number
```

You can insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
drop table if exists table1
create table table1(person_number int,  account_number int)

insert into     table1(person_number,account_number)  values(11 ,1)
insert into     table1(person_number,account_number)  values(12 ,2)
insert into     table1(person_number,account_number)  values(13 ,3)
insert into     table1(person_number,account_number)  values(14 ,4)
insert into     table1(person_number,account_number)  values(15 ,5)
drop table if exists master_table
create table master_table(account_number int,   account_balance int)

insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(1,   238989    )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(2,   4889895   )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(3,   68897     )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(4,   298729    )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(5,   387745    )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(6,   354655    )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(7,   553455    )
insert into     master_table( account_number,   account_balance)values(8,   35545     )
```

Comment: I'm going to assume that OP meant "show results for" and not "update table to only have" the relevant duplicate account numbers, esp since they gave the resultant table they want a new name. Also assuming this is someone relatively new to SQL as they are asking how to do a simple join without knowing what it is, so I don't think telling them how to insert records and drop and recreate the entire table is a good idea. If they happen to have the permissions to do that the outcome could be very bad.